# Haskell Data.Maybe *** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing

Tags: haskell, option-type

I try to write a program for an exercise. It should read a String and return an empty list if it could parse the String according to a given grammar. In case the String is not in valid grammar it should return "Nothing". Like here:

```
>prog "c+c*c$"
Just""
>prog "c+c-c$"
Nothing
```

I wrote the following functions they are loaded and compile in GHCI, but when i run `prog` with any argument i get the following exception: `*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing`

I suppose i access or pass a Maybe String in a wrong way, but not sure where. Any help regarding the right handling of Maybe structures are welcome.

Here is my code:

```
import Data.Maybe


match :: Char -> Maybe String -> Maybe String
match x input
  | (isNothing input == False) && (x == head (fromJust(input))) = Just (tail (fromJust(input)))
  | otherwise = Nothing


prog :: String -> Maybe String
prog x = match '$' (expr (Just (x)))


expr :: Maybe String -> Maybe String
expr x = ttail (term x)


term :: Maybe String -> Maybe String
term x = ftail (factor x)


ttail :: Maybe String -> Maybe String
ttail x
  | fromJust(x) == [] = Just []
  | otherwise = ttail (term (match '+' x))


factor :: Maybe String -> Maybe String
factor x = match 'c' x


ftail :: Maybe String -> Maybe String
ftail x
  | fromJust(x) == [] = Just []
  | otherwise  = ftail ( factor ( match '*' x))
```

Comment: What part of the error message in the exception isn't making sense to you?

Comment: Well basically why it occurs in the first place. In my understanding it shouldn't even exist a Nothing state when prog is executed with the valid argument String ""c+c*c$". And if the String is incorrect it shouldn't return an exception, only "Nothing".

Comment: You are using a lot of partial functions like `head,tail,fromJust` which should be avoided when possible. Using pattern matching and turning on warnings would be preferred, since it often allows the compiler to point out the cases where your program crashes.

Comment: The logic is a bit difficult to follow, but if you trace it you'll see the first `c` is matched, but then there's a `match '*'` of the rest that returns `Nothing` and you end up at `ftail Nothing`. The first guard in the definition of `ftail` tries to evaluate `fromJust Nothing` and... there's your exception!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several antipatterns in the OP's code. I'll only discuss this snippet.

```
match :: Char -> Maybe String -> Maybe String
match x input
  | (isNothing input == False) && (x == head (fromJust(input))) = Just (tail (fromJust(input)))
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

- Using `isNothing, fromJust` is an antipattern, since the latter is a partial function which crashes the program when fed with `Nothing`. The programmer has to be careful to always check `isJust` beforehand, which is easy to forget. It is much simpler to forget about these functions completely and rely on pattern matching instead (see below).
- `.. == False` should be rewritten as `not ..`
- `not (isNothing ..)` should be `isJust ..` (but again, pattern matching makes this pointless)
- `head,tail,!!` are partial functions too, and they should be replaced with pattern matching, when possible. Above, `head` is potentially called on `[]`, so we would need to check it beforehand. Pattern matching avoids the need.
- Instead of `.. == []` one can use `null ..` (or, better, pattern matching).
- Never write `f(x)` for a function call, the parentheses have no purpose there.
- Turn on warnings using the `-Wall` flag: the compiler often spots issues in the code.

If you are learning Haskell, I strongly suggest you refrain from using dangerous partial functions and read a tutorial on pattern patching, using which would prevent almost all the issues in your code.

For comparison, the code above could be rewritten as:

```
match :: Char -> Maybe String -> Maybe String
match x (Just (y:ys)) | x==y = Just ys
match _ _                    = Nothing
```

Note how pattern matching simultaneously checks whether the argument is a `Just` with a non empty list inside, and extracts the data inside the constructors. When it fails, the next case of the match is taken (instead of crashing the program).

In languages without pattern matching (say, Java), often libraries force us to remember to check whether data is present (`x.hasNext()`) before accessing the data (`x.next()`). Forgetting the check causes a runtime error / exception. With pattern matching, these two steps are combined in the same language construct, so that there is no way to "forget" a check and crash the program.

Unlike the original code, `match x (Just [])` does not crash but returns `Nothing` instead.

Comment: I like this `match` better than mine :)

Answer (score 2):

`fromJust` expects to be passed a `Just` value and it receives a `Nothing`value, this is why this exception happens:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust

Note that I would encourage you to use the [`maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybe) function which could help clarify your code I think ( and ... maybe find the bug :) )

Also, `maybe` is preferable over `fromJust` because it's not a partial function (i.e it is guaranteed that the function won't error at runtime)

for example it allows you to rewrite :

```
match :: Char -> Maybe String -> Maybe String
match x input
  | (isNothing input == False) && (x == head (fromJust(input))) = Just (tail (fromJust(input)))
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

as

```
match :: Char -> Maybe String -> Maybe String
match x input =
  maybe
    Nothing
    (\i ->
      if x == head i
        then Just $ tail i
        else Nothing)
    input
```

One more thing : `head` and `tail` are partial functions too, you'd prefer using pattern matching like this, to avoid runtime exceptions when the String is empty for example:

```
match :: Char -> Maybe String -> Maybe String
match x input =
  maybe
    Nothing
    (\i -> case i of
      [] -> Nothing
      first:rest -> 
        if x == first
          then Just rest
          else Nothing)
    input
```

(Edit: also, see the answer of @chi that gives a nice idiomatic implementation of match!)